# DFP error: "no valid network found" when uploading HTML5 creative bundles

Tags: advertising, html5, google-dfp

I wanted to upload ads for my website into DFP.   I'm trying to upload HTML5 creative bundles.

I'm following the step [Access the tool: html5-to-dfp.appspot.com](https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/6335949?hl=en), but I'm getting the the error message "***No valid network found***"

I am not able to login into https://html5-to-dfp.appspot.com
What should I do?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about a website you control. As well, it appears this may be a network issue.

Comment: Where is this error message appearing?   Is this when you try to connect to the website?   Or is this an error message that appears on the website once it is loaded?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.  All that was needed, was to enable the API access.